# ng-tags-input autocomplete should generate tags through static array of objects

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am using **ng-tags-input** in AngularJS 1 for list of countries. I don't want to use the **$http.get()** for getting the tags. I have a static array of objects that I want to utilize in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the promise angular service in your load function:

```
$q(function (resolve, reject) {
   resolve($scope.myArray);
}
```

This:

```
<auto-complete source="loadTags()"></auto-complete>
```

Would be:

```
$scope.loadTags = function () {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
       resolve($scope.myArray);
    };
};
```

`$q` creates a promise and your plugin wants that.

Don't forget to include `$q` in your dependencies.

Comment: How can I display the **$scope.myArray** specific property to autocomplete tags?

Comment: @AhmerKhan By using the method I suggested you above. It returns your array.